# Google map not loading in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I'm trying to put together a Rails app that has a bit of ajax. The problem is that the ajax parts, which call a page to load, aren't showing the Google maps. Everything else is there on the page, but not the Google maps.

When I click refresh, the page with the maps loads as it should do, but from then on, when I click on a link, the maps are missing - even though everything else in the page is there.

The script that contains my map does not even load. I mean when I put console.log("hello") between by script tags, 'hello' doesn't appear in my console. It does appear when I refresh the page, but not when using the ajax links.

Does anyone know why, or have some code to help me out? I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

at the top of my show.html.erb, but couldn't get it working. If it's any help, the code for my map script is:

```
  <div id="map_canvas">


<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("hello") 
  var map;
  var markers = [];

  function initialize_google_maps() {
    var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= @user.lat %>, <%= @user.lng %>);
    var zoom = <%= @kms_range %> > 9 ? 9 : 10;
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: zoom,
        center: currentlatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, // ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID
        streetViewControl: false
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: currentlatlng, icon:{oppacity:0}});
    map.setCenter(currentlatlng);
    map.setZoom(zoom);

    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        fillOpacity: 0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        strokeOpacity: 0.7,
        radius: <%= @kms_range %>*1000,
    });
    circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');

  }

  function show_markers() {
    if (markers)
      for(i in markers) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
      }
  }

  function add_marker(location) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    // markers.setVisible(false);
  }

  function initialize_markers() {
    <% (@reviews || []).each do |r| %>
      <% next unless r.lat && r.lng %>
      position = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= r.lat %>, <%= r.lng %>);
      add_marker(position);
    <% end %>
  }

  $(function() {
    initialize_google_maps();
    initialize_markers();
    show_markers();
  });

</script>

    </div>
```

My Ajax Code is:

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){

    var ajax_loaded = (function(response) {             

        $(".page-content")

            .html($(response).filter(".page-content"));             

        $(".page-content .ajax").on("click",ajax_load); 


});

var form_submit = (function(e) {                    
    e.preventDefault();                             

    var url = $(this).attr("action");               
    var method = $(this).attr("method");            


    var data = {}                                   
    $(this).find("input, textarea, select").each(function(i){
        var name = $(this).attr("name");            
        var value = $(this).val();                  

        data[name] =value;                          

    }); 

    $.ajax({                                        
        "url": url,                                 
        "type": method,                             
        "data": data,                               
        "success": ajax_loaded,
        "error": function () {alert("bad");}        
    });
});


var history = [];                                   

var current_url_method;                             

var ajax_load = (function(e) {                      
    e.preventDefault();                             


    history.push(this);                             

    var url =$(this).attr("href");                  
    var method = $(this).attr("data-method");       

    if (current_url_method != url + method) {       
        current_url_method = url + method;          

        $.ajax({                                    
            "url": url,                             
            "type": method,                         
            "success": ajax_loaded,                 
        });
     }
});

$("#menu a").on("click",ajax_load);

$("#menu a.main").trigger("click");
$(".search-box form").on("submit", form_submit);


});
```

Comment: show us the ajax code

Comment: ok, will put it up now.

Comment: try using `load()` for ajax since `html()` strips out script tags. `load()` has a filter mechanism for only inserting part of page and accepts and executes code. Better explanation in API docs  http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Why reload the map? Or are you trying to add additional canvases/maps?

Comment: where am I loading the map twice?

Comment: Hi  charlietti, thanks for the tip. I've modified a line of code from .html($(response).filter(".page-content")); to .load($(response).filter(".page-content")); and now nothing loads. Should I be doing something more?

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve the problem?
I have the same problem(map not show by ajax load page) before
but my problem is because I not give correct lat and lng

maybe you would  make sure value are right on your code

```
var myOptions = {
        zoom: zoom,<br>
        center: currentlatlng,<br>
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, // ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID<br>
        streetViewControl: false<br>
    };
```

and

set up your div  width and height like `＜div id="map_canvas"  style＝＂width:800px＂
 height:450px"＞＜／div＞`

I remember google map need width and height